# ng6-file-man - tree view only root folder - Angular 6

Tags: angular, file, file-upload, angular6, file-manager

For some reason, I only see the root folder in my tree view of ng6 file manager which is included in mine project. I can create new folders and I can see them in my file system but not in ng6 file manager. Did anybody had this problem or know how to resolve it?

Github repo for ng6-file-man: https://github.com/AnnotationSro/ng6-file-man

[image]

**UPDATE:** Answer - Dir must be set as true when you create a folder.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer containing post response from `api/list`. I'm creator of ng6-file-man. Also feel free to make an issue on project any time.

Comment: I forgot to set dir = true :)